Retrieve value matching with a key in 2-D array
I have a numpy array like so:
arr = np.array([[[0,0],[93]],[[2,8],[94]]])

I now want to define two variables a and b like so:
a = 2
b = 8

Now, I want to write a program that retrieves the value corresponding to [a,b] from the numpy array. In this case, the value would be 94.
How do I solve this? I am open to other ways of organizing my data as well (lists, dictionaries etc) as long as the solution is optimal. However, I want to preserve the current format of an entry in the array viz., ([inp,inp],[out])
So far, I have tried using np.where but it returns an empty array:
np.where(arr == [2,8])

>>> (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))


Arrays are typically rectangular. Yours is ragged. Arrays of lists are not efficient to work with.

If you want to look stuff up, use a dictionary. You can store a two-element key as a tuple

What version of numpy are you using? 1.26.3 raises an error for your original definition of arr.

As noted above, you'd be hard pressed to do much better than a regular Python dictionary:
x = {(0, 0): [93], (2, 8): [94]}
a = 2
b = 8
x[(a, b)]  # [94]
# This is with [93] and [94] as lists, as you have shown,
# but they can just as well be just `93` and `94` if you prefer.

For this to work, the keys need to be tuples or some other hashable type. If that doesn't work in your application, please add that information to your question. For more information about why dictionaries are perfect for this and why the key needs to be hashable, see e.g. here.

I guess you wouldn't even need to wrap the results in lists (so, e.g. 94 rather than [94]), as OP writes "the value would be 94".

Ok, then again, they write they want to preserve their format. So I guess both interpretations are valid. In any case, yours is the perfect answer, anyway :D

Note that you can only use tuples in a hashable context and not lists, because lists are modifiable after creation.

As I mentioned in the comments on the previous answer, you may only use tuples as the key to some data, and not a list in a dictionary. If you still want to use a numpy array despite what Matt has said above:
arr = np.array([[[0,0],[93]],[[2,8],[94]]]) Cannot work. Numpy is built for efficiency and will not accept an array of varying depth (it's a 3D array, but once you go two layers deep then you have 2 items, 1 item, 2 items, 1 item, which numpy does not like:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
To work around this, you can place a dummy value in arr = np.array([[[0,0],[93, DUMMY]],[[2,8],[94, DUMMY]]]) which would work although result in a decrease in efficiency.
Assuming you choose to do that, you can iteratively approach the array like so:
import numpy as np
def find_data(key1, key2, array):
    iterable = np.nditer(array)
    for index, value in enumerate(iterable):
        if index % 4 == 0:
            if key1 == value:
                if key2 == array.flat[index+1]:
                    # At this point we've found the target.
                    return array.flat[index + 2]
    return None

arr = np.array([[[0,0],[93, 0]],[[2,8],[94, 0]]])
result = find_data(2, 8, arr)
if result != None:
    print(f"Result {result}")

numpy.nditer() is the most efficient way to my knowledge of iterating over a numpy array. It flattens the array as well, such that [[[0,0],[93, 0]],[[2,8],[94, 0]]] becomes [0,0,93,0,2,8,94,0].
